# where to use private class?

Tags: c#, asp.net

So from what I understand is that if we have a private class then that class can only be accessed if that private class is in some other class which is not private.
So why do we need so much roundabout and what kind of business problem can we solve by using this?
Please give me one real-life case to use it.

Really sorry if its a repeated question.

Comment: If you don't see the use for it, just *ignore it and don't use it*. I never understand why people expect *justification* for features that they don't see immediate uses for. File it away and move on.

Answer (score 6):

Sometimes problems are that complicated. You need classes to abstract out part of solution. However, in quite rare cases that part (represented as a class or few of them) is not indendent to be consumed by the outer world, it just serves for a particular precise need. Making such a class private is ideal in that case: it keeps your namespaces clean and tidy, prevents confusion and communicates nicely the very idea, that this paticular code is nothing but an auxiliary machinery for a certain problem.

Answer (score 1):

A private class is helpful in a scenario where you need an object that would only live as part of its parent class and you need to limit its scope to its parent.

For example, say you have a Transaction object with a SecurityInfo object that you need to ensure is only accessible to the Transaction.

```
 public class Transaction 
 {
     public int ID;

     public bool ValidateSecurityInfo()
     {
           //Securityinfo can only be used within the Transaction class
           var info = new SecurityInfo();
      }

      private class SecurityInfo 
      {
      }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

I can think of [Anonymous classes/types](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/anonymous-types) as the most popular case for them.

Answer (score 0):

Nested classes have access to the parent class's private members. Therefore, with private classes, you have a mechanism for making the child classes private as well so there is no outside access to them.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var pub = new PublicClass();

        // If PrivateClass was public we could do this
        //var priv = new PublicClass.PrivateClass(pub);
        //priv.ChangeX(3);
    }
}

public class PublicClass
{
    private int _x;
    private readonly PrivateClass _privateClass;

    public PublicClass() => _privateClass = new PrivateClass(this);

    private class PrivateClass
    {
        private readonly PublicClass _publicClass;
        public PrivateClass(PublicClass publicClass)
        {
            _publicClass = publicClass;
            ChangeX(2);
        }

        // We can access our parents class's private members
        public void ChangeX(int newX) => _publicClass._x = newX;
    }
}
```